# Oracle Select with xmlquery() error - How to ignore errors?

Tags: oracle, xml

In trying to extract a subset of data from a Oracle DB table, one of the columns is XMLType, which is extracted with **xmlquery()** for relevant information.

The problem is that the XML data is from an outside source, which often gives us malformed XML with unescaped special characters.

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00244: invalid use of less-than ('<') character (use &lt;)
Error at line 1
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

It would be ok for my purposes to ignore these rows.

**How can I ignore these parse errors and have Oracle continue on with the SQL statement?**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can directly. I don't know of a way of putting the XML parser into a sort of "lax" mode where it would ignore validation errors, and you can't catch exceptions inside plain SQL.

One approach to deal with this (except harassing your outside source so that they produce valid XML, which is *the* solution) would be to validate the XML as you store it, and only process data that has been validated. You can do that simple PL/SQL code. Here's a minimal example of one way to approach this.

#### Sample table and data:

```
create table foo(id int, xml clob, valid int default null);
insert into foo(id,xml) values (1, '<?xml version="1.0"?><root><a foo="b"></a></root>');
insert into foo(id,xml) values (2, '<?xml version="1.0"?><root><a foo="<"></a></root>');
commit;
```

#### Validation function:

```
create function is_valid_xml(xml_param clob)
return int
as
  scratch xmltype;
begin
  select xmltype(xml_param) into scratch from dual;
  return 1;
exception
  when others then
    return 0;
end;
/
```

#### Applying the validation function

```
SQL> update foo set valid = is_valid_xml(xml) where valid is null;
2 rows updated.

SQL> select id, valid from foo;
ID | VALID
----------
 1 |     1
 2 |     0
```

You can then query/report based your usual criteria plus the `valid` column.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Mat's idea - just have the function return the xmltype or null, so you only go through the work of parsing once.

```
create function my_create_xml(p_clob clob) return xmltype is
  l_retval xmltype;
begin
    select xmltype(p_clob) into l_retval from dual;
    return l_retval;
exception
when others then
  if sqlcode != -31011 then raise;
  else return null;
  end if;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a check constraint that just parses the XML and checks for a root node. This will prevent them inserting rows with malformed XML. When they do that they'll get ORA-31011, not you.

e.g.

1=xmltype(clob_column_name).existsnode('/')

Of course you still need to be prepared to handle garbage that just happens to be well formed XML.